# C# RNGCryptoServiceProvider and special characters

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a way to get random characters.I need a string must be contain at 2 least uppercase letters, at least 1 number and special characters.
Here is my code:

```
public static string CreateRandomPassword(int Length)
{
    string _Chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[_!23456790";
    Byte[] randomBytes = new Byte[Length];
    var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);
    var chars = new char[Length];
    int Count = _Chars.Length;

    for(int i = 0;i<Length;i++)
    {
        chars[i] = _Chars[(int)randomBytes[i] % Count];
    }
    return new string(chars);
}
```

some results:

ZNQzvUPFKOL3x

BQSEkKHXACGO

They haven't special characters and numbers.

Comment: The chances for your algorithm to create a string (a password?) with a special characters are quite low as your alphabet just provides three of them (`[_!`).

Comment: Seperate strings of lower case alphabet, upper case alphabet, numbers, special characters.... Generate a random set of these strings and mix them in a random way. (There may be better ways)

Comment: You might as well just save yourself some effort and use a guid. Way more random due to length and equally impossible for a human to remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code works great! I've just wrapped it with a function that validate your conditions.

I've executed the following:

```
public static string CreateRandomPassword(int Length)
    {
        string _Chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[_!23456790";
        Byte[] randomBytes = new Byte[Length];
        var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);
        var chars = new char[Length];
        int Count = _Chars.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
        {
            chars[i] = _Chars[(int)randomBytes[i] % Count];
        }
        return new string(chars);
    }

    public static string CreateRandomPasswordWith2UpperAnd1NumberAnd1Special(int length)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var pass = CreateRandomPassword(length);
            int upper=0, num =0, special = 0,lower=0;
            foreach (var c in pass)
            {
                if (c > 'A' && c < 'Z')
                {
                    upper++;
                }
                else if (c > 'a' && c < 'z')
                {
                    lower++;
                }
                else if (c > '0' && c < '9')
                {
                    num++;
                }
                else
                {
                    special++;
                }
            }
            if (upper>=2&&num>=1&&1>=special)
            {
                return pass;
            }
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void CreateRandomPassword_Length13_RandomPasswordWithNumbers()
    {
        var random = CreateRandomPasswordWith2UpperAnd1NumberAnd1Special(13);
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!It's perfect.Your code have given me strong password. Replace else{ special++; } with } else if (c == '[' || c == '_' || c=='!'){ special++; } to to make sure get special characters.

Comment: Up vote it if you've used it , BTW you don't have to verify the special because it can't be anything else...

Comment: else if (c == '[' || c == '_' || c=='!'){ special++; } it take a lot of memory.

Comment: instead of if (c > 'A' && c < 'Z') etc it needs to say if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'), otherwise A and Z are not counted as uppercase. same for the lowercase and numbers.